# Powershell Select-Object -match or?

Tags: powershell

Can the select-Object be used like so to match either?

```
If ((Get-content $file | select-object -last 1) -match 'deleted' -or 'return'){"yes"} else {"No"}
```

This doesn't produce error but will tell me yes regardless of the last string matched in $file.  I would like to do display a Yes if either match.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use alternation in the regex:

```
If ((Get-content $file | select-object -last 1) -match 'deleted|return'){"yes"} else {"No"}
```